# Grafana variable and Prometheus query

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

I have a problem trying to create a custom variable of type `query` with this formula :

```
label_values(increase(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{namespace=~"$Namespace"}[10m])>0,ingress)
```

When I play this query against the prometheus server (without "label_values" which is a grafan templating function) it works fine.

I have the following toast error :

```
Template variables could not be initialized: parse error at char 9: could not parse remaining input "(nginx_ingress_"...
```

The aim of this variable is to list only Ingress labels that had an activity during the last 10m.

Comment: Looks to me like the error is in the template variable definition, rather than having anything to do with Prometheus.

Answer (score 1):

`label_values(metric,label)` is a [Grafana function](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable), not a Prometheus function.  Since it only takes a metric (not a timeseries/vector), you just want:

```
label_values(nginx_ingress_controller_requests,ingress)
```

I don't think you can restrict by namespace in the custom variable query.